# how can I avoid download the same file by the conditional loop?

Tags: python, loops, file

I am trying to download multiples, but from multi resources . my `href` contains multiples `link_pdf` , but at moment to check the folder . it downloads the same file while I am using `while counter < max_results:` , but if I remove it. I got what I want , but I want if I tell download 10 or 1k then downloads 10 even if its skips some files from my filters

```
while counter < max_results:
  print(href)
  r = requests.get(href)
  local_file = open('{}/testcase-{:06d}.{}'.format(OUTPUT_DIR, counter, extension), 'wb')
  local_file.write(r.content)
  counter += 1
  print("Total Files {} downloaded".format(counter))
```

Comment: Can't you just use a if statement and check if you already downloaded that file?

Comment: how can I do it with `while` instead of `for` ?

Comment: do what? and you use a `while` and not a `for`.

Answer (score 0):

place above your request

```
if os.path.exists('{}/testcase-{:06d}.{}'.format(OUTPUT_DIR, counter, extension)):
    continue

r = requests.get(href)
....
```

check if the file exists and if it does don't make a request